# Show linear transformation $F(\pmb{u})= \langle \pmb{u}, \pmb{c} \rangle \pmb{b} - \langle \pmb{b},\pmb{c} \rangle \pmb{u}$has a basis of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following problem:

> Let $V$ be an $n>0$ dimensional vector space. Show the linear transformation $F(\pmb{u})= \langle \pmb{u}, \pmb{c} \rangle \pmb{b} - \langle \pmb{b},\pmb{c} \rangle \pmb{u}$, where $\pmb{b},\pmb{c} \in V; \langle \pmb{b}, \pmb {c}\rangle \neq 0$, on $V$ has a basis of eigenvectors and find its matrix with respect to such a basis.

My first instinct was to check for symmetry and then apply the spectral theorem, but it is not a symmetric linear transformation according to my calculation, as

$$\langle F(\pmb{u}),\pmb{v}\rangle = \langle \pmb{u},\pmb{c}\rangle \langle \pmb{b},\pmb{v}\rangle - \langle \pmb{b},\pmb{c}\rangle \langle \pmb{u},\pmb{v}\rangle$$

$$\langle \pmb{u}, F(\pmb{v})\rangle = \langle \pmb{u},\pmb{b}\rangle \langle \pmb{v},\pmb{c}\rangle - \langle \pmb{b},\pmb{c}\rangle \langle \pmb{u},\pmb{v}\rangle$$

Perhaps I might be missing some identity for inner products. Otherwise, the proof might need more rigour.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a typo in the linear transformation? If $F(u) = \langle u, c \rangle b - \langle u, b \rangle c$ then everything should work out fine due to skew-symmetry.

Comment: @VHarisop The condition $\langle b,c \rangle \neq 0$ is equivalent to the diagonalizability of the transformation as written, so I'm inclined to believe that there's no typo.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** We can write this transformation as $F(u) = [G - \langle b,c\rangle \operatorname{id}](u)$, where id denotes the identity transformation and
$$
G(u) = \langle u,c \rangle b.
$$
Note that adding a multiple of the identity to a transformation has no effect on its eigenvectors, so it suffices to find the eigenvectors of the transformation $G$.

The kernel of $G$ is the eigenspace of $G$ associated with the eigenvalue $0$; how does this eigenspace relate to $b$ and $c$? What additional eigenvector does this transformation have, and how can we see that this eigenvector is not an element of the kernel?

Comment: Could you possibly give me another hint? I've been struggling for a long time trying to find the eigenvalues. My current approach was to find the matrix of $G(u)=\langle u,c \rangle \pmb{b}$, which I found to be $[c_1 \pmb{b},c_2 \pmb{b} ... c_n \pmb{b}]$ Where do I go from here?

Comment: @William Well you know that one of the eigenvalues of $G$ is $0$. If $G(u)$ is non-zero, then you know that $G(u)$ is a multiple of $b$. So, if $u$ is an eigenvector of $G$ associated with a non-zero eigenvalue, then $u$ is...

Comment: Parallel to b? @BenGrossman

Comment: @William Exactly. Now, plug in a vector parallel to $b$ (for example, $b$ itself) and verify that it's an eigenvector

Comment: But doesn't that mean we only have two eigenvalues? Being $0$ and $\langle b,c \rangle$ ? I'm sorry to have to ask this many questions. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @William Yes, we only have two eigenvalues. However, associated with the eigenvalue $0$ of $G$, we have $n-1$ elements of the eigenvector basis.